# How to change data values of button after certain operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a shopping website where a customer can add or remove items from my store. When a customer add a item in cart I want to give option to remove that item by changing data-value action.

for adding item in cart

```
<button data-button='Action':'Add to cart','item-id':'$itemid'>Add to cart</button>
```

and when click on above add to cart,  the button should changed to

```
<button data-button='Action':'Remove from cart','item-id':'$itemid'>Remove</button>
```

so how can I change data-button's action from 'add to cart' to 'Remove from cart' using jquery or javascript

Comment: Instead of doing that, could you not just have the two buttons with a show and hide JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('button').attr('data-button',$('button').attr('data-button').replace('Add to cart','Remove from cart'))
```

Comment: Yes This is a solution but it will remove other part 'item-id':'$itemid' also. I only want to change action

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate,

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var btn = $(this).data('button');
    $(this).data('button', btn.replace('Add to cart','Remove from cart'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply manipulate with classes in order to provide different functionality of the same button:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.remove', function() {
  $("<div/>").text('Item removed! ID:' + $(this).data('id')).appendTo($("#results"));
  $(this).text("Add to cart").removeClass("remove").addClass("add");
});

$(document).on('click', 'button.add', function() {
  $("<div/>").text('Item added! ID:' + $(this).data('id')).appendTo($("#results"));
  $(this).text("Remove from cart").removeClass("add").addClass("remove");
});
```

```css
button.remove {
  color: red;
}

button.add {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-id="$itemid" class="add">Add to cart</button>

<div id="results">
</div>
```